# Command Line Optimization Level in NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have written an assembly code to add ten numbers using byte variables, and code is error free.

**Assembly code:**

```
 ; a program to add ten numbers using byte variables
[org 0x0100]

jmp start 
num1: dw   10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50
result: dw 0 

start: 
    ; initialize stuff 
    mov  ax, 0              ; reset the accumulator 
    mov  bx, 0              ; set the counter   
    outerloop: 
        add  ax, [num1 + bx]
        add  bx, 2
        cmp bx, 20          ; sets ZF=1 when they are equal, 
                            ;un set ZF=0, if they are not equal  
        jne  outerloop 
    mov  [result], ax


    mov  ax, 0x4c00
    int  0x21
```

While assembling this code in NASM facing this error.

[image]

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/nasm

Comment: The switch to specify an output filename is `-o`, not capital `-O`. Capital `-O` specifies the optimisation level (defaults to `-Ox` in recent NASM).

Comment: By the way, those are not byte variables nor byte registers, `dw` and `ax` both indicate word size. (On the 8086 a word is two bytes sized.) And you should uncomment the `mov ax, 4C00h` to properly terminate your program.

Comment: In 8086 Ax and Bx are 16 bits which is equal to 1 word :)

Comment: @Engr.KhuramShahzad: Indeed, and bytes are generally 8 bits, so why would you describe your example as "using byte variables"? It's using word variables, not byte.

Comment: Yes, you are right. but one word == 2 byte== 16 bits. same thing if we say its one word or 2 bytes or 16 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NASM's command line options are case sensitive.  It looks like you wanted to use the [`-o` option](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.1) (lower case `o`) to specify the output file name, so that `-o C02-06.COM` would write the output to a file named `C02-06.COM`.  Instead you used [upper-case `-O`](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.24), which requests optimization and (with your version) requires an additional flag, as the message says.

So change your command to `-o C02-06.COM` and it should work.